# MSB4062 error publishing .NET7 app with publish profile

Tags: wpf, azure-pipelines, publish, .net-7.0

This is pretty easy to replicate but also code here:

https://github.com/dominicshaw/dotnet-publish-error

- create an empty wpf project using .NET7
- create a publish profile for ClickOnce
- publish via command line (not visual studio)

Publish profile is almost totally standard ([view here](https://github.com/dominicshaw/dotnet-publish-error/blob/main/PublishError/Properties/PublishProfiles/ClickOnceProfile.pubxml))

Command line from project directory:

`dotnet publish PublishError.csproj -p:PublishProfile=ClickOnceProfile`

Subsequent error:

```
MSBuild version 17.4.0+18d5aef85 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4149,5): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.RequiresFr
amework35SP1Assembly" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKey
Token=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, a
nd that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [C:\Users\shawd\source\repos\PublishError\Publi
shError\PublishError.csproj]
```

I have the latest SDKs installed and VS2022 up to date. This only happens via command line - I am able to publish from Visual Studio (I am setting up devops, so require command line).

This happens regardless of adding nuget package for Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core. Note however nuget package v15.1.0.0 is not available - I have tried 15.1.548 and the latest instead.

Totally at a loss! Any ideas very welcome.

Thanks vm

Comment: `RequiresFramework35SP1Assembly` <-- You didn't notice anything odd about the task name?

Comment: [The documentation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core/#readme-body-tab) for `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core` says "**You do not need to reference this package**"

Comment: @Dai i did but I honestly have no idea how to "add" Framework35SP1...?

Comment: Do you have any pre-release versions of the .NET SDK installed?

Comment: No - here is a total list -
2.1.526
2.1.700
2.1.701
2.1.801
2.1.802
2.2.300
3.0.101
3.1.100
5.0.414
6.0.302
6.0.303
6.0.400
7.0.100

Comment: @Dai Does it work for you?

Comment: I can't test it, I don't have VS2022 on my machine right now, sorry.

Comment: The latest version of [Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core/) has been updated to 17.4.0, which support .net 7.0, you could try to edit with `Include="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core" Version="17.4.0"` and test again

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT same behaviour - it is always using 15.1.0.0 according to the output, regardless of what is referenced. I think this is the core of the problem; that the dotnet cli appears to be using an old MSBuild/

Comment: Hi, Dominic, I did clone your repo to local, and did no change but “FolderProfile”. Given that the doc tells that, we could use “dotnet pubulish ” without “-p”, but the command would still refer to the default path for the profile, and I also managed to do that. So I suppose that ‘-p:PublishProfile=ClickOnceProfile’ will change the path where the command would search for the profile.

Comment: @DominicShaw hi, dominic, wha's the latest status of your project?

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT I have read thru your answer but I can't get it working. Perhaps you could do a PR on the repo with your changes? Note that it is vital the clickonce files are generated - running with the FolderProfile does complete, but does not produce these files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial answer as my workaround for anyone struggling with a similar problem:

I have found it impossible to do this with the dotnet cli but I can do it with MSBuild if I specifically target 17.4 (VS2022). By default, my Azure DevOps Server 2020 capability is the 2019 MSBuild (15.X), so I have to be explicit:

`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /restore /Verbosity:m /t:Publish /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64 /p:configuration=Release /p:PublishProfile=ClickOnceProfile`

This works - so in my pipeline I have created a batch file which runs this, then I copy the files to my ClickOnce location.

Not ideal, but a working pipeline.

Interesting side note - this dotnet cli command which should be idenitical (and indeed uses the correct 17.4 MSBuild) - does not work (with the same error):

`dotnet msbuild -target:Publish -property:RuntimeIdentifiers=win-x64;Configuration=Release;PublishProfile=ClickOnceProfile`

Comment: Hi dominic, thanks for you sharing. and i suppose that you could highlight your answer to benefit more developers by accepting answer

Answer (score 1):

During the tests with your project and files, I finally managed to publish it successfully with the command `dotnet publish PublishError.csproj -p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile`.

Here is the document for [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#msbuild), as is referred,

> The preceding example uses the FolderProfile.pubxml file that is found
> in the <project_folder>/Properties/PublishProfiles folder. If you
> specify a path and file extension when setting the PublishProfile
> property, they are ignored. MSBuild by default looks in the
> Properties/PublishProfiles folder and assumes the pubxml file
> extension.

And I also succeeded with `dotnet publish` with your project.

==============================

**update on 11/19**

So I suppose that the issue is resulted from your definition for `-p:PublishProfile=ClickOnceProfile`,it will change the path where this command would search for the publish file

Comment: Can you show me the publish profile you used? The project does not have a "FolderProfile", only "ClickOnceProfile" - did you add a new profile?

Comment: See https://github.com/dominicshaw/dotnet-publish-error/tree/main/PublishError/Properties/PublishProfiles

Comment: @DominicShaw hi, have you checked again and does it publish correctly?

Comment: appologies I have been unwell. The publish happens, but it does not create the click once files - you need a clickonce profile to do that - i.e. with <PublishProtocol>ClickOnce</PublishProtocol> - in that case, it fails

Comment: @DominicShaw do you mean add the `<publishProtocol>` in the property of the .csproj? what the error do you get? From my test, it was `MSB3094`. And when I changed it to `<PublishProtocol>ClickOnceProfile</PublishProtocol>`, it could succeed again.

Comment: Sorry I can't get that working at all - perhaps you can do a PR? Note that it is vital that the ClickOnce publish is generated with the versioning in the profile; using FolderProfile completes, but does not generate these files